# Overlooking conditional convergence in function series

Tags: calculus

I noticed that many times when we want to check convergence of function series we overlooking conditional convergence.

For example: (Was taken from Calculus 2 by Benzion Kon 2010)

> Find the convergence area of the following series:
>
> $$(1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n}(\frac{1-x}{1+x})^n$$
>
> Solution:      Let's look at $$(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert  
>  \frac{(-1)^n}{2n}(\frac{1-x}{1+x})^n\rvert= \sum_{n=1}^\infty
> \frac{1}{2n}\lvert   (\frac{1-x}{1+x})\rvert^n$$
>
> For any $x_0$ (2) is positive series so from Cauchy theorem we can say
>   that it convergence if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2n}\lvert
> (\frac{1-x}{1+x})\rvert^n}<1$$ or $$\lvert\frac{1-x}{1+x}\rvert^n<1$$
>
> It happens when $x>0$. So series (2) convergent if $x>0$ and diverges
>   if $x<0$ so the original series converge absolutely if $x>0$ and
>   diverges if $x<0$. We can check what happenes for $x=0$ and to see
>   that it will converge.

I'm  trying to undertand why as opposed to numerical series they didn't check if the series has conditional convergence.

Comment: For the region in which the limit is $<1$ you get absolute convergence. For the points in which the limit is $>1$ they get divergence *because the terms of the series don't tend to zero*. For the points in which the limit is equal to $1$, yes, they need to check the original series.

Comment: ... and there is when you get to play with the series $\sum_n \frac{(-1)^n}{2n}$.

Comment: For this specific examples you right.  I also saw other exercises that they didn't check it and the series tend to zero.